# Data Source on US Wage Earnings

Tags: data-request

Does any guys know how to find the data source of US individual wage earnings from 1920 to 2018?

Comment: FRED. Obligatory charecters.

Comment: At what level? Nation, state, county, individual? And are you looking for **annual** data dating back to 1920?

Comment: Thank you to @Paul. I need individual and annual data. May be it is hard to find it.

Comment: @Yang-Hui Please update your question accordingly to make it clearer. For data questions, you may also try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **annual** individual-level earnings data:

- From 1962: try Current Population Survey (CPS) https://cps.ipums.org/cps/intro.shtml
- From 2000, try American Community Survey (ACS) https://usa.ipums.org/usa/acs.shtml

For **decadal** individual-level census data:

- From 1850: IPUMS-USA https://usa.ipums.org/usa-action/faq#ques0